# netbeans and xdebug with laravel

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug, laravel

Has anyone had any success in netbeans getting xdebug working with laravel?  I'm not sure how to configure it with laravel.Right now I have the following:

under project properties-> run configuration, I have:

```
 Project url: http://localhost/m1/

 Index file: public/index.php

 Arguments: user/bob/task/1
```

However, the xdebug never appears to advance past the public/index.php file.

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I m getting the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Under the Properties -> Sources you also need to set correct web root:

`Web Root: public`

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans and xdebug working without any problems with Laravel. Do you have an other working projekt running with xdebug? Or was this you first attempt?